# Check for non-empty variables

Tags: php

I have to check,say 20 variables. & I'm really confused between these two approaches to check whether **all** of them are non-empty.

First one is your basic approach:

```
if($var1!= null && $var2!= null && $var3!= null && $var4!= null...) {
    // Do this
}
```

Second approach is by using array which I got from [here](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/209955-check-that-multiple-variables-arent-empty/?p=1096057):

```
$vars = array('var1','var2','var3','var4');

$errors = array();         
foreach ($vars as $var => $label)
{
    if (isset($$var) && strlen($$var) == 0)
        $errors[$var] = $label . 'is empty';
}

if(is_array($errors) && count($errors) > 0)
{
    echo 'Please fix the following errors: ';
    echo '<ul><li>' . implode('</li><li>', $errors) . '</li></ul>';
}
else
{   
        //Do this
}
```

Now, like I said earlier, the variables in my situation are around 20. Which approach(*If there are more, I would love to hear about them*) do you suggest would be better(*And more PHP-like if I may add*), if the number of variables are as small as 20?
Also, please be kind enough to explain as I'm still an newbee.

Thanks

Comment: Second approach is good doesn't matter how many variable you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second attempt is ok, but this line:

```
if (isset($$var) && strlen($$var) == 0)
```

might be:

```
if (empty($$var))
```

.. depending on your needs. If using `empty()`, variables which have been set to:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

will be treated as *empty*

Comment: Could you please tell me the cases in which we use `isset` & `strlen` then?

Comment: `strlen()` assumes `$$var` is a string, but `isset()` does not check this. While PHP will automatically cast scalar variables to string when passed to `strlen()` it will not cast arrays and objects. So using `strlen()` is quite fragile, it will work with scalar variables only.

Comment: @shaktimaan There is one difference you need to know before using my solution: `strlen("0");` will return `int(1)` which evaluates to true in this case. `!empty("0")` would return `false`. Is this ok for you?

Comment: Yes its perfectly fine as I'm using it in a form,which doesn't have any _zeroes_. Thanks

Comment: `The second attempt is ok` . The `ok` here made me more curious. Is there a better way?

Comment: You might use `array_walk()`. If the array of variables is large or the task needs to be done often per script then it might improve the performance as it will not require a foreach loop in  PHP code.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have 10 such vars with that same naming convention as in your question. You could do

```
<?php

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $var = "var$i";
    if (!empty($$var)) {
        // this one at $i is set
    } else {
        // not set
    }
}
```

You can just change the loop's upper limit to count for the number of variables that you have. Without having to first generate an array of names by hand. But still if you have so many variables with same name and just the index is different then you're better off using an array in the first place.

Comment: Although this is a useful answer, but this doesn't seem so _PHP-like_. But then I'm a newbee ;)

Comment: Haha very  nice comment I like it. Could you please let me know why it doesn't look like PHP? maybe I can improve

Comment: Like I said, I'm a newbee & don't want to offend the big guns. But this seemed a little more like the other languages. And yes, this answer works too, no doubt

Comment: Aha you talk good :) And no you didn't offend anyone, and nor am I a big gun. You are perfectly entitled to your opinion and I like it :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function.

```
function noneEmpty($array) {
    foreach ($array as $variable)
        if (empty($variable))
            return false;
    return true;
```

Comment: This approach seems too easy to be true ;) Let me try this